# What does the word "across" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

There are two people talking and facing each other. One person says "we need to go to the garage to get the car, it's the building **across from us** with the red roof"

What can this mean?
I know "across" means:

1. On, at, or from the other side of: *across the street*.(source TFD)

So it means on the other side of the street but i've no idea what across from us might mean.

Answer (score 3):

Webster has [an entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/across%20from) for "across from": *on the opposite side from (someone or something)*. Lexico simply [defines](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/across_from) it as *OPPOSITE*.

But perhaps the confusion is that the construction "across from" always implies an extra noun, which might be left unsaid. In this case, a building is probably "across [the street] from us." If I said "At dinner, I sat across from Peter," I'm probably across [the table] from him.

Comment: I forgot to mention that where the conversation takes place there is a fence between the people talking and the building. Could it be possible that this is why it was said that way?

Comment: Then perhaps it's across [the fence]. I think I only just now understand your confusion: Is it that the people are facing each other, and therefore in opposite directions? But yes, my answer still holds; the two people count as a group, and the building is "opposite" the group, with something in between (like a fence, an alley, a courtyard, etc.)